# Pass foreach loop in function

Tags: php, foreach

Just wondering if we can do something like below:

I want to pass foreach loop in function as attribute.

```
<?php

TestMethodForEach( foreach($_POST['activity'] as $activityID){ $activityID; } );

?>
```

How can I achieve this functionality in php?

Here is my real code:

```
<?php

 $accountServices->RL_ChangeInActivities(
                            new IhcStructRL_ChangeInActivities(
                                new IhcStructChangeActivity(
                                '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
                                $accountID,
                                $_POST['serviceID'],
                                '1',
                                'IhcStructChangeActivity',
                                'teset,etsagad, asdfasd',
                                    new IhcStructArrayOfAccountActivity(
                                            new IhcStructAccountActivity(
                                                '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
                                                'activityID 1',
                                                $accountID,
                                                'IhcStructAccountActivity',
                                                'ActivityNumber'
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    );

  ?>
```

Actually i want to repeat this object IhcStructArrayOfAccountActivity.

You will see ( ActivityID 1 ) in this object (new IhcStructAccountActivity) so i have more then 5 activity ID or may be more, doesnt matter. so how can i repeat this object dynamically so this should appear like

```
 <?php

new IhcStructArrayOfAccountActivity(
new IhcStructAccountActivity(
'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
'activityID 1',
$accountID,
'IhcStructAccountActivity',
'ActivityNumber'
)
)

 new IhcStructArrayOfAccountActivity(
new IhcStructAccountActivity(
'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
'activityID 2',
$accountID,
'IhcStructAccountActivity',
'ActivityNumber'
)
)

 new IhcStructArrayOfAccountActivity(
new IhcStructAccountActivity(
'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
'activityID 3',
$accountID,
'IhcStructAccountActivity',
'ActivityNumber'
)
)

 ?>
```

Hope you understand now.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What's the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: You've already written the code, why not just run it and answer your own question?

Comment: Yes bro i belive it doesnt making any sense but is there any way like this? actually i want to repeat the value in xml.

Comment: Do the old Reverse-a-roo for the same result

Comment: I have update the code, please have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
    foreach ($_POST['acitivity'] as $activityID) {
        TestMethodForEach($activityID);
    }
?>
```

Or `array_walk` will do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

The right code is :

```
<?php  foreach($_POST['activity'] as $activityID) {
        TestMethodForEach($activityID;);
       }
 ?>
```

i hope that is what you're looking for